# Javaで圧縮したファイルを解凍してオブジェクトとして読み込む

Tags: java, java8

オブジェクトを`ObjectOutputStream`で書き出して`JarOutputStream`でJarファイルにて、
そのJarファイルを`JarInputStream`で読み込んで`ObjectInputStream`のコンストラクターを呼び出したところで例外が飛んできます…
以下のようなことをしていますが、どうにも成功しません。

### 出力

①オブジェクトを`ObjectOutputStream`で一時出力

②出力された一時ファイルを`ObjectInputStream`で読み込む

③ストリームからbyte[]を取得

④`JarOutputStream`で書き出し

圧縮しなければ問題ないので、①と②に問題はないかと…

具体的には

```
//一時ファイル書き出しは省略
//tempFileは書き出した場所とおなじFileクラス。

//例外処理省略

byte[] objectData = ObjectInput(tempFile);//読み込む

jos = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("test.jar")));
jos.setMethod(JarOutputStream.STORED); //無圧縮を指定

JarEntry entry = new JarEntry("data");  //格納ファイル名

entry.setSize(objectData.length);   //データサイズをセット

CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
crc.update(objectData);
entry.setCrc(crc.getValue());   //CRCをセット

jos.putNextEntry(entry);
jos.write(objectData);

/* 条件によって複数ファイル格納 */
//テスト時はファイルいっこだけで試してみました。

jos.flush();
```

最初の`ObjectInput`はこんな感じになってます

```
public static byte[] ObjectInput(File file) throws IOException{

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        ois.read(data);

        ois.close();
        return data;
    }
```

出力自体は成功してるように思います。
出力されたファイル内のtestが格納されており、
ファイルサイズがもとの一時ファイルと一致しているので…

CRCがメタデータなのか、ファイルに含まれるのか、
よくわからないのでそこが原因かもしれませんが…

### 読み込み

①指定されたファイル(ここでは上記したファイルを読み込む)を`JarInputStream`で読み込む

②`.getNextJarEntry()`を使ってJarEntryを取得

(ファイルは正しいものとして進めさせてください。実際圧縮しなければ読み込めました。)

③`FileOutputStream`で一時出力

④一時ファイルを`ObjectInputStream`で読み込む←ここで例外が飛ぶ

⑤オブジェクトを`.readObject()`で取得

例外の内容としては、
`java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000`

もし圧縮すると、
`java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 504B0304`

という例外が同じところで飛んできます。

あとなんかハイライトされなんですけど、私が悪いんでしょうか(^_^;)

---

バイト列を用いることで解決しました。
失礼しました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
byte[] objectData = ObjectInput(tempFile);//読み込む
```

この部分の`ObjectInput`メソッドの戻り値`objectData`を、例えば次のようなメソッドで出力してみるとわかりますが、想定されたように読み込まれていません。
(おそらく全て`0`で出力されると思います。)

```
private static void print(byte[] objectData) {
    for(byte c : objectData) {
        System.out.format("%d ", c);
    }
}
```

つまり`ObjectInput`メソッドの実装に問題があります(ので、「圧縮しなければ問題ない」というのは何か勘違いをされているかと)。

ここでやりたいのは、ファイルをバイト列として読み込みたいだけなので、`ObjectInputStream`ではなく`FileInputStream`が適切だと思います。
したがって、`ObjectInput`メソッドは次のように実装することになります。

```
public static byte[] ObjectInput(File file) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];

    fis.read(data);

    fis.close();
    return data;
}
```

---

「バイト列を用いることで解決しました」というのがよく理解できなかったのですが、[こちら](https://teratail.com/questions/23013)の書き込みから想像するに、一時ファイルの作成をやめた(`ObjectInput`を使用しなくなった)ということですかね。
確かにこの処理自体不要です。

---

そんなわけで経緯をよく理解できていないのですが、オブジェクトをjarファイルに出力したいのであれば、あまり深く考えずに、そういうストリームを構築すれば良いのでは無いかと思います。

オブジェクトを書き出したいので`ObjectOutputStream`を使う、それをjar圧縮して最終的にファイルに、となるとそれぞれ`JarOutputStream`, `FileOutputStream`なのでこれらをつなげて

```
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));
```

…としたいところですが、このままですと`JarOutputStream`の作法に従っていないというエラーが出ますのでその部分を修正します。
そうすると以下の`compress`メソッドのような感じになるかと思います。
(また、本件タイトルに沿った「Javaで圧縮したファイルを解凍してオブジェクトとして読み込む」メソッドが`decompress`です。)

```
void compress(File jar, Asset target) throws IOException {
    try (JarOutputStream jos = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(jar))) {
        JarEntry ze = new JarEntry("asset");
        jos.putNextEntry(ze);
        try (ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(jos)) {
            os.writeObject(target);
        }
    }
}

Asset decompress(File jar) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try (JarInputStream jis = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(jar))) {
        jis.getNextJarEntry();
        try (ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(jis)) {
            return (Asset) is.readObject();
        }
    }
}
```

上記は無圧縮jarではないですが、敢えて圧縮しないのであればわざわざ`JarOutputStream`を使わず直接`FileOutputStream`を使うのが楽だと思います。

全体はここに挿入するには長くなってしまったので[外部サイト(gist)](https://gist.github.com/yukihane/b14133de6f40d8fb8750)に置いています。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！
どっちかというと、OutputStreamとかのコンストラクターにOutputStreamを渡す意味が分かっていなかったかなーと思います。。。
とても勉強になりました、ありがとうございます。
ソースコード助かりました。
あと、わざわざ別サイトまで往復させてすみません…